# Handling many admins in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

If a company has departments A, B, C, D ...and each have to have a admin different . Only admins of the particular department can create, update and delete the information of their respective departments. My question is how to implement to create API ?

Comment: use [django-guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian) for setting object level permission

Comment: Also you can use django admin groups and users to assign permissions based on each app to any person

Comment: I was thinking of using custom authentication on API views while creating,updating or deleting info ?